# Asana API: organization_exports

Tags: asana

How do I get organization ID? I tried this:

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/organization_exports
```

But it returns

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Not Found","help":"For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"}]}
```

Of course I'm logged in, or use an access token, and other API calls work fine.

My final goal is to make use of the organization ID in https://github.com/Asana/export_importer.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay - the system that was supposed to alert us to your question didn't pick this one up.

The easiest way to get the organization ID is to query our API for your user to see what organizations you're a member of, rather than use the `organization_exports` endpoint - that's for exporting a full organization data dump for backup or reporting purposes.

If you look at our [API documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/users#get-single) for getting your user at `app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me`, you'll see that your user record returns a list of workspaces which have ID and name information. This is probably the most straightforward way to get your organization ID from our API.

Comment: So, in "workspaces":[{"id":xxxxxxxxxx,"name":"xxxxxxxx"}], the 'id' is organization ID? A bit confusing, if anything else.